# Jersey Rest API returns immediate and the long task continues

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jersey, java-threads

I've a requirement in my project where a user calls an REST API - POST Operation to perform a long waiting task, now instead of making the user wait, we want to immediately notify user saying "Task Accepted" and in the background fire another thread to carry out the long task.

I've tried the below code, but the moment the API returns the other threads don't log any messages or performs any task. What am I missing here.

```
@POST
@Path("/longtask")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response longTask() {
    LOGGER.info("longTask started by Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    executor.submit(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new AsyncService().longTask();
                }
            });       
    LOGGER.info("longTask completed by Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return Response.ok(new MyResponse<>("Task Accepted")).build();
}
```

AsyncService

```
public class AsyncService {

    /**
     *
     */
    public void longTask(){
        LOGGER.info("AsyncService - longTask() Started: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try{
            //Tried thenAcceptAsync as well
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new MyAsyncSupplier()).thenAccept(new MyAsyncConsumer());
        }finally{
            LOGGER.info("AsyncService - longTask() Completed: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }   

}
```

MyAsyncSupplier() and MyAsyncConsumer() are some task that calls the DB and performs long waiting task. 
The loggers under MyAsyncSupplier() and MyAsyncConsumer() are not printed. I tried the same with just a sample java project and main() method and the same happened. The moment the main completes the System.out's are not printed.

```
[744832b5-deed-4043-11-111] [myproject] 2018-10-08 18:19:16,836 [http-nio-8080-exec-31] INFO  mypackage.MyResource - longTask started by Thread: http-nio-8080-exec-31
[744832b5-deed-4043-11-111] [myproject] 2018-10-08 18:19:16,836 [http-nio-8080-exec-31] INFO  mypackage.MyResource - longTask completed by Thread: http-nio-8080-exec-31
[] [] 2018-10-08 18:19:16,837 [pool-64-thread-1] INFO  mypackage.AsyncService - AsyncService - longTask() Started: pool-64-thread-1
[744832b5-deed-4043-11-11] [myproject] 2018-10-08 18:19:16,844 [http-nio-8080-exec-31] DEBUG mypackage.InitializationResponseFilter - Media Type set to : application/json
```

How can I make this task continue?

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new MyAsyncSupplier()).thenAccept(new MyAsyncConsumer());
```

### Update 1:

The above code was not working due to the MyAsyncSupplier and MyAsyncConsumer Classes had some Object assignment issues. I debugged the code further and upon fixing those it worked.

### Update 2:

In-fact there was no need to have executor submit.

```
@POST
@Path("/longtask")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response longTask() {
    LOGGER.info("longTask started by Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    new AsyncService().longTask();
    LOGGER.info("longTask completed by Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return Response.ok(new MyResponse<>("Task Accepted")).build();
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  you say nothing is logged after /longtask returns but in your logs you clearly see AsyncService starting after the complete message is printed.  Also did you remember to put a wait or loop in the main to keep it alive.  the JVM is killed once main is done.  That is why your simple java project doesn't work.

Comment: The loggers are before the CompleableFuture that’s getting printed. The once by MySupplier and MyConsumer are not logged and performed in DB. If I add a wait, won’t that make the main thread to wait?

Answer (score -1):

I think the code you posted is fine and works as expected.  Maybe your implementation of MyAsyncSupplier and MyAsyncSupplier is wrong.  Here is my implementation give it a shot.

```
public class FunFun {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunFun f = new FunFun();
        f.longTask();
        f.shutdown();
//        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); changed to use shutdown.
//        scanner.nextLine();
//        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public String longTask() {
        System.out.println("longTask started by Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        executor.submit(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new AsyncService().longTask();
                    }
                });
        System.out.println("longTask completed by Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return "Task Accepted";
    }

    public class AsyncService {
        public void longTask(){
            System.out.println("AsyncService - longTask() Started: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try{
                //Tried thenAcceptAsync as well
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new MyAsyncSupplier()).   thenAcceptAsync(new MyAsyncConsumer());
            }finally{
                System.out.println("AsyncService - longTask() Completed: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyAsyncSupplier implements Supplier<String>{

        @Override
        public String get() {
            System.out.println("Supplying Food");
            return "Food";
        }

    }

    public class MyAsyncConsumer implements Consumer<String>{

        @Override
        public void accept(String t) {
            System.out.println("Nom Nom " + t);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
longTask started by Thread: main
longTask completed by Thread: main
AsyncService - longTask() Started: pool-1-thread-1
Supplying Food
Nom Nom Food
AsyncService - longTask() Completed: pool-1-thread-1
```

Comment: If you down vote at least tell me why so I can learn from it.

Comment: Charles, I'm not sure who/why the down vote. But IMO I feel there is no need of the "scanner" and "System.exit(0)" code.

Comment: well in this case because you have an executor it's going to keep the program running if you don't have the System.exit(0); A better solution would of been to shutdown the executor.  Also noticed that the thenAccept is not using the thenAcceptAsync.  And you are right the longTask does not need the executor, But you can use it on the supplyAsync and AccpetAsync calls it would give you more control.  Also if you feel the post helped you can up vote or even accept answer.  No pressure but I do like rep :)